# At how many battery cycles should I consider replacing my battery?

Tags: battery, power, charge

My battery has become quite a pain in the neck recently, It's not lasting much more than about 2 or 3 hours and that's usually just using basic programs like chrome or pages etc. It's difficult for me because I use it quite a lot at school, and unfortunately school is a lot longer than 2-3 hours...I also use a lot of very intensive programs like blender and unity, but usually I try to only do that at home with my charger.

[image]

At the moment it tells me I've done 621 cycles and tells me its in normal condition (pfft, normal...) Is that actually normal? Also, should I be thinking about replacing it with a new one, if so, is it expensive and will it actually make much of a difference, and if it shouldn't be replaced what can I do to make it better?

Thanks, Matthew

Edit:

This is what CoconutBattery tells me:
[image]

Comment: Depending on the model, you can probably get upward of 1000+ cycles. For most MacBooks, 1000 is the normal expected battery life cycle. After 1000, it's time for a replacement.

Comment: Off-Topic but use Safari; Chrome kills your battery

Comment: @user104317 I literally just made that switch last night!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charge Cycle means nothing, assume you plugged in all the time for 5 or 6 years, the cycle is still 0 but does it mean your battery is 100% health? No.

You should search for your macbook model to find out what is the design capacity of your macbook, and divided by your current max full charge capacity to find out the health of the battery. Or you may download some software that help you to calculate automatically.

Let say for the below screenshot, macbook pro design capacity is 8450mah, but now my maximum charge is 8429mah, so the health is 8429/8450 = 99.8%

[image]

Comment: Thats interesting, how do I get to that window then?

Comment: Nevermind, found it, that doesn't seem that bad does it...and yet it drains so quickly, so if I were to replace it, do you think it would actually make a difference?

Comment: You should have 80% of original running time theoretically, if it is really draining much faster than expected, you can if the fan is running at full speed or is it running many background process. You can also try to reset SMC.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned what's the model of the Mac you are using, Apple's [Determining battery cycle count for Mac notebooks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585)  will tell you more about the Charge Cycle.

Also in case you are still in warranty, which I assume you are not cause of so many charge cycles, you can go to the Apple Store and get the battery diagnosed, if they find a problem they will replace it.